# Linq-to-SQL with complex Type Inheritance and Eager Loading (DataLoadOptions LoadWith)

Tags: inheritance, linq-to-sql

This seems to be a common problem, but I can't find any solution which would allow me to get what I want.

I have a database with a main table for my application's entities. This table has a "Type" column and L2S instantiates the correct derived class with the discriminator property value. I have about 10 different entity types with a few inheritance levels. This works perfectly.

I want to have a way to create some "GetEntityById()" and maybe even a "GetAllEntities()" functions which read the database and return a fully loaded entity usable offline after the datacontext is closed, so I need to eager load some relationships too. This is where I use L2S DataLoadOptions.

Depending on the type of the entity, different things are loaded. Some of the things loaded also use type inheritance mapping

For example I would like to be able to do this:

```
options.LoadWith<Entity>(p => p.CommonClass);
options.LoadWith<DerivedEntity1>(p => p.Foo);
options.LoadWith<DerivedEntity2>(p => p.Bar);
options.LoadWith<Bar>(p => p.EvenMoreSpecificClass);
options.LoadWith<DerivedBar>(p => p.EvenMoreSpecificClass2);
```

Now, of course, if I load an entity of type DerivedEntity1, I wouldn't expect the rules for loading the EvenMoreSpecificClass/EvenMoreSpecificClass2 to have any impact.

Now I step back a little and found out that only using this line is problematic:

```
options.LoadWith<DerivedEntity2>(p => p.Bar);
```

Since Bar has Type Inheritance rules, L2S handles it pretty badly. I profiled the queries and the problem I have seems to be exactly the same as described here (tons of useless OUTER JOIN): http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/361683/using-dataloadoptions-with-a-linq-to-sql-inheritance-hierarchy-results-in-multiple-sql-left-joins . Unfortunately, the workaround can't be applied because I can't specify different Include rules based on the base type with this method.

Just loading a single inherited entity with a single inherited one-to-one relationship takes 10 seconds and generates an amazing amount of join. When pushing the LoadWith rules a bit further and loading more than one entities at once, I would expect it to take some time and complete with an extreme query, but it's even worse: the whole operating system begin to sporadically freeze. I never experienced this behavior before (usually you can just kill the process), and it does the exact same thing on another PC and both are quite powerful so something is clearly wrong here.

Now, my questions are:

- Is what I'm trying to do possible and logical or is my data architecture design broken in some way?
- Is there any way I can obtain what I aim for using a different method?
- Would switching to Entity Framework help me in any way for this situation? (From what I've read, not really).

Comment: I have no solutions, but since my SQL model is converted back and forth to a more complex model used by the rest of the application, I simply merged the DerivedBar class into a single Bar class and the incredible slowdown stopped. Then I can map to my application model DerivedBar manually depending on the type variable and not let L2S do it for me. This prevent me to do the specific LoadWith<DerivedBar> rules, but since I only had one case like this in my entire model it's not that important for me.